# Is there a decent browser-based javascript self-editor?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

Is there a decent browser-based javascript self-editor?

It is obvious one can make a quick js editor with a page containing a form textarea, some buttons and callbacks.  I'm wondering if someone has taken that as a beginning and ran with it.

The javascript to be edited could be defined in a global string or it could be a served .js

The ideal editor would show a pretty version inside a browser window and provide some kind of development environment for editing the script.

It is understood that user-written scripts would only exist inside the browser and could not be saved without some additional server-side functionality.  The ideal package would discuss and explore this.... but I'd settle for anything that just lets the user make their own simple changes to 100-200 line scripts.

Comment: If jsbin could be attached to an existing page that would be about the right idea.  But all the answers people have posted are all interesting.  Further suggestions are appreciated.  

JUSH http://jush.sourceforge.net/ looks interesting for markup of existing code because it links back to documentation.

For my particular application I'm running prototype.js already, which may affect what else I can load in an execution environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for, but does [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 3):

The hard part of what it sounds like you want to do is going to be parsing the javascript so that you can do intelligent things with it. The [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) library can help you develop something to put on a page.

UPDATE:

Etherpad isn't around anymore but [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org) is really nice. It's got a long history and is the engine used by the [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/)

Answer (score 2):

There is

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress
- http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea&sess=4b049cee4477f0820c82231b09e80a91
- http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/

Answer (score 2):

Do also check out [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are also integrated solutions which, in addition to browser-based online editing of JavaScript code, do other things for you, like running the JS code in the browser or hosting it for you.

If you're interested in those, try [Erbix.com](http://www.erbix.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[coderun](http://www.coderun.com/ide/)